# jQuery functions stop working on page load with ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

this is the first time i m try to do something load pages with ajax.

This is works fine on a couple pages, but somepages with a slide or another jquery function, the scripts stop working, i see something about i need to call the functions again, but i dont know where on my code is the right place, like i need to call on loaded page.

there is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
preload([
'/img/bg_body_topo.jpg',
'/img/img_topo.png',
'/img/logo_topo.png'
]);  

 $("a[rel*=outside]").attr( "target", "_blank" );
 $('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar({ sizethumb: 55 });
 $('#menu-topo ul li ul').hide();
 $('#menu-topo ul li').hover(function(e) {
 $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeToggle("fast");
 });

 $("#home-slide-destaques").scrollable({ circular: true }).autoscroll({ autoplay: true     }).navigator(".controles");         
  // DISCOGRAFIA
  $("ul#int-abas-discografia").tabs("div#int-conteudo-discografia > div", { effect: 'fade' });
  // INTEGRANTES
  $("ul#int-abas-integrantes").tabs("div#int-conteudo-integrantes > div", { effect: 'fade' });


 var content = $('#content');  
 //pre carregando o gif  
    loading = new Image(); loading.src = '/img/103.gif';  
    $('#menu-topo a, a#menu-ajax').live('click', function( e ){  
        e.preventDefault();  

                var tHeight = $('#wrapper').height();
                var tWidth = $('#wrapper').width();
                var posicao = $('#wrapper').position();

                $('#carregando').remove();
                $('#imgcarregando').remove();

                $('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="carregando"></div>   <div id="imgcarregando"> <img src="/img/103.gif" style="margin:280px 0 0 0;" alt="Carregando"/></div>');

                $('#carregando').css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'width': tWidth,
                    'height': tHeight,
                    'top': posicao.top,
                    'left': posicao.left,
                    'background': '#000',
                    'opacity': '.60',
                    'z-index': '9900',
                    'text-align': 'center'
                });


                $('#imgcarregando').css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'width': tWidth,
                    'height': tHeight,
                    'top': posicao.top,
                    'left': posicao.left,
                    'background': '#000 url(/img/logo_topo.png) center 200px no-repeat',
                    'padding': '30px 0 0 0 ',
                    'opacity': '.88',
                    'z-index': '9999',
                    'text-align': 'center'
                });


                    content.html( '' );  


        var href = $( this ).attr('href');  
        $.ajax({  
            url: href,  
            success: function( response ){  
                //forçando o parser  
             var data = $( '<div>'+response+'</div>' ).find('#content').html();  

                //apenas atrasando a troca, para mostrarmos o loading  
                window.setTimeout( function(){  
                    content.fadeOut('slow', function(){  

                         $('#carregando').fadeOut('slow');
                         $('#imgcarregando').fadeOut('slow');
                         $('#content').height('auto');
                            // DESTAQUES

                         content.html( data ).fadeIn(); 

                    });  
                }, 1000 );  
            }  
        });  

    });                        

});  

     function preload(arrayOfImages) {
     $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    // Alternatively you could use:
    // (new Image()).src = this;
     });
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a javascript debugger, like google chrome has or firebug?

Comment: hi @derabbink I open the webpage everything works fine, i go to any link, and open the page fine, but if i go on a internal page with any javascript function just dont works, like the page with a slide. on javascript console dont show any error

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem a couple days ago and managed to solve it with [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), which is executed everytime an ajax load is complete

Did something similar to:

```
var rebindButtons = function(){
   $(elements).unbind('click').click(function(){
       // rebinding of button functionality
   });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  // we bind the buttons for the first time
  rebindButtons();
  // and when there's an ajax call completed we rebind the buttons
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    rebindButtons();
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to load old usual html pages in you new ajax page. When you load a new content, you don't load the script for it as it was woring before, you need to load them too.
You can try to do it by yourself, inserting the appropiate scripts in a new  tag via ajax, or simply loading all appropiate scripts for all the contents at beggining, or I suggest you load them when you need it with a library like require.js, that is already optimized for it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the right way, but i did some changes and 99% works now..

i have chage

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

// to

$(function(){
```

also i have make this with the javascript functions

```
function boxWallpapers(){


$("#home-slide-destaques").scrollable({ circular: true }).autoscroll({ autoplay: true }).navigator(".controles");          

     // DISCOGRAFIA
$("ul#int-abas-discografia").tabs("div#int-conteudo-discografia > div", { effect: 'fade' });

   // INTEGRANTES
$("ul#int-abas-integrantes").tabs("div#int-conteudo-integrantes > div", { effect: 'fade' });

$('#menu-topo ul li ul').hide();
$('#menu-topo ul li').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeToggle("fast");
});

  }
```

and then on the ajax

```
      $.ajax({  
            url: href,  
            success: function( response ){  
                //forçando o parser  

             var data = $('<div>'+response+'</div>').find('#content').html();  

                //apenas atrasando a troca, para mostrarmos o loading  
                window.setTimeout( function(){  
                    content.fadeOut('slow', function(){  

                         $('#carregando').fadeOut('slow');
                         $('#imgcarregando').fadeOut('slow');
                         $('#content').height('auto');


                         content.html( data ).fadeIn(); 
                         boxWallpapers();  // HERE HERE



                    });  
                }, 1000 );
```